# Making all questions show their answers on click in accordion FAQ

Tags: javascript, toggle, addeventlistener

I'm working on the Frontend Mentor FAQ Card Accordion challenge and am trying to get all my FAQ questions to show their answers.

I successfully created an event listener that displays the answer to the question, but it's only working for the first div element in the HTML. (i.e. only the first of my 5 questions shows it's respective answer when clicked).

My HTML includes 5 "question-title" classes with each "question-title" having it's own "answer hide" paragraph.

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
//title to each faq question 
const questionTitles = document.querySelector(".question-title");
//the answer to each faq question
const answer = document.querySelector(".answer");

// When the question title is clicked
questionTitles.addEventListener("click", function () {
    answer.classList.toggle("hide")
})
```

I've also tried

```
questionTitles.forEach(question => {
    question.addEventListener('click', () => {
        question.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hide")
    })
})
```

but receive the error message "Uncaught TypeError: questionTitles.forEach is not a function", I'm assuming because forEach should only be used on arrays???

Any advice you could give would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

QuerySelector is awlays selects the first element.
No matter you foreach it it awlays is the first one.

Please catch with `querySelectorAll` and it will give you an array with a same selector HTML objects and your second block of code is going to work.

Comment: I added querySelectorAll and it's logging out "hello" for all of them (which is good!). Now I'm struggling to get the answer to show up. I've tried 
answer.classList.toggle("hide") and that doesn't work regardless of answer=document.querySelectorAll or just querySelector. What am I missing?

Comment: can you see in the source if the hide class is being added and removed from the element, if it is its a css issue, it could also be being added to an incorrect element  or their may be an error in your console, its hard to know without seeing the rest of the code

Comment: You can try answer.classList.add('hide'); answer.classList.remove('hide'); manually